# How to add label for timeseries line google flutter chart?

Tags: charts, flutter

I am using charts_flutter package to display charts in my flutter app, as far as I know, we use labelAccessorFn to show labels in Pie Chart but it's not working for time series line chart.

For the Bar chart, We can add the label as below
https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/horizontal_bar_label

I want to implement the same for the time-series line chart.

So I have added
`labelAccessorFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales.toString()`,

at
https://github.com/google/charts/blob/master/charts_flutter/example/lib/time_series_chart/simple.dart

but Not get success

Answer (score 0):

You can use RangeAnnotation for the same which provides label styling as well.

behaviors: [charts.RangeAnnotation(new charts.LineAnnotationSegment())]

Change the properties as per your requirement. I wanted to show a custom vertical line as well.

Comment: Can you give source code which display Label on line chart

Comment: This answer can't be used on TimeSeriesChart. Flutter will error with `The argument type 'LineAnnotationSegment' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<AnnotationSegment>'`. How can you adapt this to a TimeSeriesChart?